# Pandas Groupby to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame in this format

```
a   b
yes 1
yes 2
no  3
yes 1
no  4
no  3
no  4
```

I need to to get unique combination of yes & no like this,

```
a   b
yes 1
yes 2
no  3
no  4
```

Then create a dictionary from this where my column A will be key & column b will be value. Can you please suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
d = df.drop_duplicates().set_index('a').to_dict()['b']
```